# Projection parameters from WGS84 UTM37 to Ain El Abd UTM37 and the reverse

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, coordinate-system

I am developing application using JavaScript apis,

I want the correct projection parameters to convert from WGS84 UTM37 to Ain El Abd UTM37 and the reverse.

When I click in the map I get Ain El Abd Coords from the map onClick event. I need to convert these to WGS84 for display in the Web App.

Answer (score 1):

The proj string for AeA UTM 37N is

```
+proj=utm +zone=37 +ellps=intl +towgs84=-143,-236,7,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs
```

and the one for WGS84 UTM 37N is

```
+proj=utm +zone=37 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs
```